How to make dynamodb streams trigger at PK level
I am planning to create dynamoDB table with 3 columns



Req ID
ISIN
MKEY
Date




A1
111
U111
03/07/24


A1
222
U222
03/07/24


A2
333
U333
03/07/24



Assuming I loaded these records today at same time. I wanted to trigger dynamodb streams twice here - One for A1 and one for A2, And not for each record insert. Is it possible to do that? MKEY is kind of unique key or PK
As per my knowledge ddb streams capture the record and attribute level updates. this is how aws keeps the global tables in sync. Not sure what I have specified will work.

You can never be sure that your items will go to a different shard or not. The mapping between a DynamoDB partition and a Lambda consumer is like this:
DDB Partition -> Stream Shard -> Lambda invocation
While the scenario you are looking for is most likely to occur, it's not guaranteed for 2 reasons:

Both your partition keys A1, A2 could hash to the same physical partition, meaning you will see A1 and A2 in the same Lambda invocation.
Your item collection A1 may be stored across several partitions, meaning they would end up in different lambdas consumers.


Thanks ! I am fine to trigger only one Lambda say L1 for A1 and A2 both request IDs. The intension is for every item from A1 - in my example there are two records, I DONT want to trigger L1 twice, it should be once when whole set pertaining to A1 is loaded.

Yes, just set the batch size to something your happy with, and lambda will wait until it has enough items to fulfill the batch before invoking.
